# How to determine if parameter is correct type in Generics

Tags: java, generics, casting, dictionary, error-handling

I'm writing a map implementation with the following required method signature.

I need to ensure value is of the correct type.  I thought this check would cause an exception if two types were not equal, but it doesn't. Is there anyway to check for this?

```
public boolean containsValue(Object value) {

    try {
        V temp = (V) value;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ClassCastException("Value is not of correct type");
    }
    ...
```

Comment: The compiler would have issued a warning for that generic cast.  Don't ignore those warnings.

Comment: by requiring it to be of type V you are breaking the contract of the `containsValue()` method, which returns true when there exists a value `v` in the Map where `value.equals(v)` (or if they are both null), regardless of the class of `value`

Answer (score 4):

Because of type erasure you cannot use the standard `instanceof` operator. The canonical approach is to pass the class itself or an instance of it somewhere.

Then you can use reflection to check the instance type:

```
private Class<V> clazz; // somehow this gets set

public boolean containsValue(Object value){

    if(clazz.isInstance(value)){
        // safe:
        V temp = (V) value;
    }
```

You can also check the inheritance tree using [`Class.isAssignableFrom`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29):

```
    if(clazz.isAssignableFrom(value.getClass())){
        // safe:
        V temp = (V) value;
    }
```

Note this guarantees that this is a type-safe cast but does not require the types to be the same, e.g. `V` could be `Number`, but `value` could be of type `Integer`.

As far as getting `clazz`, you can enforce it in your constructor:

```
public class MyMap<K,V>{

    private final Class<V> clazz;

    public MyMap(Class<V> clazz){
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

...
```

And your initializer for the class might look something like:

```
 MyMap<Integer,String> foo = new MyMap<Integer,String>(String.class);
```

I'm generally in favor of passing the type in the constructor for this kind of thing and marking the field as `final` since the semantics and restrictions would then prevent you from changing that field, which is reasonable since the instance generally relies on compile-time guarantees that assume the type parameters are unchanged.

Comment: Alright, I'm kind of getting what you're saying, but how and where do I put the clazz thing?

Comment: @Jeff: It just needs to be a field in your class. I recommend setting its value in your constructor.

Comment: So, it seems like this:

     public class MyMap<K,V>{
       public MyMap(Class<V> clazz){
          this.clazz = clazz;
     }

is its own separate constructor?

How does that integrate with the one I already have written?

Comment: @Jeff: you need to modify your current constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need the value to be of type V? The Map interface was defined this way not by accident.

You should rather accept the value being an Object and then invoke value.equals(someOtherValueInYourMap).

For example:

```
public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
    V v1 = ...;
    V v2 = ...;
    V v3 = ...;
    return value.equals(v1) || value.equals(v2) || value.equals(v3);
}
```

assuming there are three values in your map v1, v2, v3.
It doesn't matter what's the type of v1, v2, v3 and the argument value, cause the equals method is defined in Object and you can always call it to compare objects. If value is really of a different type that can't be compared with V instances, then its equals method will throw an ClassCastException and unless you catch it, it will be propagated further. Don't worry about it.

Comment: +1 people always try to force the object to be the value's type, which contradicts the specification of the method in Map

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't throw an exception is because the map can't contain an object of a different type, so false is the correct answer.

As for your question, thanks to type-erasure, no there is no way of seeing if the passed object is the same as the generic type.

Comment: `value` is an external object passed in; not an object in the map